# Yii Cgridview filter not working?

Tags: yii

I am trying to implement a dropdown filter in Cgridview,   The column is from another table.

```
 //model search code 

  //person table 
   public function search(){
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
      $criteria->alias='per';      
    $criteria->compare('LastName',$this->LastName,true);    
    $criteria->compare('FirstName',$this->FirstName,true);         
     $criteria->join='right JOIN person_surveys ps ON ps.id = per.P_Id'; 

   }
  //relation to person survey

   public function relations()
{

    return array(

        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'PersonSurvey', 'P_Id'),

    ); 

}

   //person survey table model search 

    public function search()
{


    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;    
    $criteria->compare('person_id',$this->person_id,true);    
    $criteria->compare('survey_ids',$this->survey_ids,true);          
     $criteria->join='left JOIN persons ps ON ps.id = per.P_Id';  

   }  

   //controller 
   public function actiongriddisplay(){

        $model2=new Persons('search'); 
         if(isset($_GET['ajax'])){ 

        $model2->attributes =$_GET['Persons'];
        $this->render('griddisplay',array('model2'=>$model2));    
        }

        else{

            $this->render('griddisplay',array('model2'=>$model2)); 
     }


    }

    //in view file

    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(      
        'dataProvider' => $model2->Search(),
        'filter' => $model2,
        'ajaxType'=>'GET',
       // 'ajaxUpdate'=>'items',
        //'ajaxUrl' =>$this->createUrl('userManagement'),   
        'columns' => array(             
              array(
         'name' => 'FirstName',
         'header'=>'Full Name', 

            ),
           array(
     'name' => 'user.survey_ids',
     'header'=>'Survey ids',    

    'filter'=>CHtml::activeDropDownList($model2  ,'survey_ids', array('224'=>'224','223'=>'223','225'=>'225')),  

           'value'=>'isset($data->user->survey_ids)?$data->user->survey_ids:null'

        ),
```

I have put the search on, in models. why is the dropdown filter not working?
Why this is not working please help?

Comment: what error you are getting while running this code? can you please post here?

Comment: The code is not getting any error. It is displaying the Grid, with dropdown in the surveyid column, but the dropdown is not filtering the column. It is just refreshing the page,displaying the entire column without  filtering.

Comment: did you try with 'ajaxType'=>'POST' method?

Comment: Tried like that, POST array is empty in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

This link (http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/) will solve your problem.